# Is it possible to use ArrayBuilder without trimming the result?

Tags: scala

The ArrayBuilder result() method usually has to perform a copy of the internal array, just to trim off any unused slots at the end.  But copying is not guaranteed - when the internal array is exactly the right size, it is returned without copying.

Can anyone see a way to use ArrayBuilder without incurring this cost, in applications where an independent size variable makes trimming unnecessary?

**Update**: I don't know the size before-hand, and thus don't don't want to pre-allocate.  It is an integer array, and I want to avoid the boxing overhead of ArrayBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are mutable, there's no need to use a builder, you can just insert into the `Array` directly.

As you know the size in advance, use `Array.ofDim()` to create the `Array` with exactly the right size before you start.

Comment: I think @EdStaub do not know the size in advance, this is the reason he tries to use ArrayBuilder, but he does not like the array copy when he calls result(). I think he can safely use the ArrayBuffer instead of ArrayBuilder if I understand correctly.

Comment: @GáborBakos Yes, and no.  You're right that I don't know the size before-hand; I'm discovering it in the act of filling the array.  I want to avoid ArrayBuffer because of the boxing overhead.  I should have said in the original post, and have updated - it's an array of ints.